# Why is the Dart compiler not erroring when I extend an abstract interface class?

Tags: dart

While learning Dart and reading the official [docs](https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers#abstract-interface) on abstract interface classes, I am confused by the way they work. Why can an abstract interface class be extended without error?

I tried to verify what I thought I understood by making sure that the implementation of the abstract interface was valid and extending the abstract interface was invalid, but both are coming out valid.

```dart
void main() {
  MyClassImpl();
}

abstract interface class MyClass {
  int return4();
}

class MyClassExt extends MyClass {
  @override
  int return4() => 4;
}

class MyClassImpl implements MyClass {
  @override
  int return4() => 4;
}
```

[Dartpad with the above code](https://dartpad.dev/952d903f76fde1c62652ee8198a5cd7b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, since I missed an important part of what defines an interface.

An interface can be implemented but not extended outside of its own library. The sample provided is all within the same library.